# Testing Google Cloud Vision with Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-cloud-platform

I am testing Google Cloud Vision with Java in Eclipse.

I have copied the java code from https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library

import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature.Type;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Image;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class QuickstartSample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    try (ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {

      // The path to the image file to annotate
      String fileName = "./resources/wakeupcat.jpg";

      // Reads the image file into memory
      Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
      byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
      ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

      // Builds the image annotation request
      List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
      Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
      Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.LABEL_DETECTION).build();
      AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder()
          .addFeatures(feat)
          .setImage(img)
          .build();
      requests.add(request);

      // Performs label detection on the image file
      BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
      List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

      for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
        if (res.hasError()) {
          System.out.printf("Error: %s\n", res.getError().getMessage());
          return;
        }

        for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getLabelAnnotationsList()) {
          annotation.getAllFields().forEach((k, v) ->
              System.out.printf("%s : %s\n", k, v.toString()));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where can I download the .JAR's from so that everything compiles properly?

Google themselves say (see the link above)

> If you are using Maven, add this to your pom.xml file:

```
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>  
    <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>  
    <version>1.14.0</version> </dependency>
```

However, I am not using Maven (nor Gradle or SBT which are their other suggestions).

So I thought to open a New Maven project in Eclipse, which would then download all the JAR's automatically, and then copy them across to my project.

So I did "new Maven Project" in Eclipse and then when it said "enter a group id for the artifact" I entered the details from Google as I pasted above, but it did not download anything.

Any ideas how I can get the JARs so that the code will compile?

The pom.xml file which was auto-generated by Eclipse is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
  <version>1.14.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>google-cloud-vision</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: If you are not using maven you can search for all the JARs manually - https://mvnrepository.com/ , then download what you need and add to the project and include to your classpath.

Comment: If you decide to use Maven - provide your pom.xml also , maybe there is smth. wrong.

Comment: @john - I added the pom.xml file as you suggested.

Comment: added as an answer to have better formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, when you have Maven you can add your dependency.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- THIS IS YOUR APP RELATED STUFF -->
  <groupId>com.your.app.group.id</groupId> <!-- YOU SHOULD PROVIDE THIS -->
  <artifactId>your-app-name</artifactId> <!-- YOU SHOULD PROVIDE THIS -->
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <!-- THIS ARE YOUR APP dependencies -->
  <!-- Google lib should be declared here -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And if this dependency is in Maven Central - Maven will download it.

Comment: OK. So I replaced my pom.xml with the one suggested by @john. I did not make any changes whatsoever (even to the section "This is your App Related Stuff") and then all the dependencies were downloaded! Great!